# Cannot connect to Mysql Socket

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-2002

I have an AWS server. I have mysql running and it connects just find to my RDS server, but I want a local mysql instance running. When I type mysql into the command prompt I get the following.

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)

my.conf is as follows

```
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
#socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
socket=/tmp/mysql.sock
user=mysql
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0
```

Running find mysql.sock does not return any results.

Comment: Are you specifying the "socket" option twice in this my.cnf or is this just a bug in the posting?

Comment: I think I was messing around with the conf file - I believe that /var/lib is the original (which is now commented out) I get the same error no matter which line is uncommented

Answer (score 1):

Look at the mysql process(es) running:

```
ps -aef | grep mysql
```

Look for something like

```
--socket=/path/mysql.sock
```

Fix my.cnf to reflect the correct path and name.

**OR**

As mysql or root user:

```
lsof | grep mysql.sock
```

Comment: ps -aef | grep mysql returns ec2-user 14405 13825  0 02:27 pts/0    00:00:00 grep mysql - The other command does not return anything. That tells me that mysql is running but mysql.sock is not running correct?

Comment: This tells me that mysql may not be running. You can try one more thing, see if you can connect via the TCPIP connection instead of using the socket: `mysql --host=127.0.0.1 --port=3306 --user=username --password=password`.

Comment: ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111) 
So I ran this
sudo yum groupinstall "MySQL Database"

Package mysql-5.1.47-1.2.amzn1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package unixODBC-2.2.14-11.3.amzn1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package mysql-server-5.1.47-1.2.amzn1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package MySQL-python-1.2.3-0.3.c1.1.4.amzn1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package perl-DBD-MySQL-4.013-3.2.amzn1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
No packages in any requested group available to install or update

Comment: rpm -qa | grep -i mysql
MySQL-python-1.2.3-0.3.c1.1.4.amzn1.x86_64
mysql-libs-5.1.47-1.2.amzn1.x86_64
mysql-server-5.1.47-1.2.amzn1.x86_64
php-mysql-5.3.5-1.11.13.amzn1.x86_64
perl-DBD-MySQL-4.013-3.2.amzn1.x86_64
mysql-5.1.47-1.2.amzn1.x86_64
mysql-devel-5.1.47-1.2.amzn1.x86_64

Comment: This seemed to help me - I can log into mysql now http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/04/yum-groupinstall-mysql-database/

Comment: So was MySQL running or did you need to start it?

Comment: Okay so I confirmed that mysql was already installed. I guess I just had to start it with service mysqld start - I really thought that I tried that. Thanks for helping me focus on the problem for a couple of days.

Comment: A big THANK YOU! I solved by symlinking the socket I found with your command in /tmp/mysql.sock